# TV white space transmitters and receivers

Tags: wifi, networking, television

I heard the TV white space (Radio) is unallocated frequency given to broadcasting services. been reading about the superwifi using this frequency and thought how one can use it for personal use.

**Q1:** My question is, if i wanted to send data from one computer to another using white space which equipments can i use to transfer data, can existing tv receivers and transmitters be used or what are the best devices to use?